# How can I reset the scratch / preview buffer height?

Tags: scratch-buffer

When performing autocompletion on PHP or javascript, vim opens a scratch buffer which contains info about the function being autocompleted.
Unfortunately, I increased the height of this scratch buffer by 8 lines with
<kbd>C-w</kbd>, <kbd>8</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>

Now the scratch buffer always opens really large (about 10 lines high).
Even closing and restarting vim makes no difference.
How can I reset the behaviour for this scratch buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "preview window" and you can read all about it in `:help preview-window`.

The `'previewheight'` option should be what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks romainl, it worked exactly as you said! interesting that the setting persisted that way. vim usually flushes all settings - not saved into `vimrc` at shutdown.

Comment: Do you use sessions?

Comment: no, I dont know what sessions are. do you recommend them?